# Lightning:input "input" id is not unique - preventing click of checkbox-button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am aware of both `.getLocalId()` and `.getGlobalId()` for `lightning:input` it seems that there's also an `id` that connects the `<label for>` to the `<input id>`.

I've found a scenario where this is **not unique** and presenting itself as an issue when using `lightning:input type="checkbox-button"`.

Using a Lightning Console application, it's possible to load multiple tabs and get a repeated `<input id>` in some other tab which is the SAME `id` value as `lighting:input`. It just so happens that the `type="checkbox-button"` requires unique pairing.

It's a bit hard to reproduce but this psuedocode is all I'm doing:

```
<aura:iteration ...>
  <lightning:input aura:id="checkbox-button"
    name="{! 'checkboxButton_' + v.rowIndex }"
    type="checkbox-button"
    label="none"
    variant="label-hidden"
    disabled="{! v.isDisabled }"
    checked="{! v.isSelected }"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Which outputs the following html on the DOM:

```
<lightning-input data-aura-rendered-by="3082:0" lightning-input_input="">
  <div class="slds-form-element" lightning-input_input="">
    <div class="slds-checkbox_add-button" lightning-input_input="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="input-80" name="checkboxButton_0" value="" class="slds-assistive-text" lightning-input_input="">
      <label for="input-80" class="slds-checkbox_faux" lightning-input_input="">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text" lightning-input_input="">none</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</lightning-input>
```

Global Id is indeed unique, but has no influence on the `id="input-80"`. providing a `name` doesn't help either. I've also checked the suite of `aria` attributes on the component and they have no influence on the `id` / `for` pairing.

This seems to happen when multiple tabs are open in Lightning Console and you reload the browser page. I've currently just used SLDS style html to remake the `lightning:input type="checkbox-button"` so that seems to be working. So then, my questions are:

- Are there any workarounds for this?
- Is the workaround to just use a regular Lightning App?
- Has anyone else encountered this behavior?

Comment: Are you saying that the same `id="input-80"` is generated (by `lightning:input`) in multiple tabs in the console view? If so, sounds like a bug in `lightning:input` (perhaps present in other components).

Comment: @KeithC precisely this, however i'm seeing the issue with lower number inputs and only sometimes. `"input-31"` seems to be where I'm hitting it mostly.